# Greenplum loading data from table to file using external table

Tags: greenplum

I ran the below create script and it created the table:-

```
Create writable external table FLTR (like dbname.FLTR)
LOCATION ('gpfdist://172.90.38.190:8081/fltr.out')
FORMAT 'CSV' (DELIMITER ',' NULL '') 
DISTRIBUTED BY (fltr_key);
```

But when I tried inserting into the file like `insert into fltr.out select * from dbname.fltr`
I got the below error, `cannot find server connection`.

Please help me out

Comment: Is there actually a server running at 172.90.38.190 ? If so, this questions is perhaps better suited for your network admin, or perhaps superUser.

Answer (score 0):

I think your gpfdist is probably not running try:

`gpfdist -p 8081 -l ~/gpfdist.log -d ~/ &`

on 172.90.38.190.

This will start gpfidist using your home directory as the data directory.

When I do that my inserts work and create a file ~/fltr.out